# Average across images and then interpolate out nans

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scipy

I've got a stack of satellite images that are all taken within a short time period but none of them provide sufficient coverage of my study area. So I would like to:

1. Average them all together - ignoring nans if there is at least one other valid data point in that location
2. interpolate over the array to fill in holes - unless there isn't a valid data point with n-pixels of that location. If that is the case I'll just keep it as a nan and ignore it in the final processing.

So far I have:

```
initial_satellite_data.shape
>>> (5, 500, 500, 2)
# This is five images, 500x500 pixels, and two bands per image.

# need to convert this to float in order to do the next step
sat_data_float = initial_satellite_data.astype(np.float32)

# 255 values signify areas without data, so converting that to nan
sat_data_float[sat_data_float==255]=np.nan

# get the average across the different images
average_image = np.nanmean(np_imageset, axis=0)

average_image.shape
>>> (500, 500, 2)
```

But I'm not clear on how I can interpolate across the data to fill in the gaps that still contain nan data along with my caveat of not wanting to interpolate if the pixel doesn't have valid data with n-pixels of it.

As an example of roughly how the data could appear here is some code generating the kind of noise that I do want to interpolate out and the kind of missing chunks I don't want to interpolate across on a single band image:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 500)
y = x[:, None]
average_image = x + y

# Destroy some values - this is about the amount of missing 
# data I have that I want to interpolate across
mask = np.random.random(average_image.shape) > 0.98
average_image[mask] = np.nan

# Now destroy a whole corner that might be missing and it 
# doesn't make sense to interpolate into this mass of missing data
average_image[0:80, 0:80] = np.nan

# Here should be some interpolation process, I've been able to interpolate in 1D across the row and that actually works well 
# enough to get rid of the missing individual pixels but I can't do a sanity check to make sure it isn't interpolating a pixel 50 pixels away from real data.
interpolated_image = average_image

fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(1, 2)

ax0.imshow(average_image, cmap='gray', interpolation='nearest')
ax0.set_title('Input image')
ax1.imshow(interpolated_image, cmap='gray', interpolation='nearest')
ax1.set_title('Interpolated data')
plt.show()
```

[image: matplotlib output]

Comment: you can use an nxn neighborhood around nan pixels and assign average value to that pixel

Comment: If you share some data and identify a location where you do and a location where you don't want to interpolate, I will have a try tomorrow. Also tell me `n` and whether it is measured horizontally, vertically or in any direction.

Comment: Hi @MarkSetchell I've added some example data with details. I think `n` should be 3 pixels and measured in any direction.